# How to handle null values while parsing XML in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML into my domain model. Below is the code part

```
Customer customer = new Customer();

IEnumerable<XElement> elements = XElement.Load(xmlPath).Elements();

customer.ID = elements
                .Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "customers")
                .Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "id")
                .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Some time XML does not contain the section "customer" so the first .Where() clause returns *null* and further processing like .Elements()... causes it to throw an exception.

My question is on how do I just stop at the first .Where() clause if I the section doesn't exist in the XML (i.e. A *null* is returned) and move forward without getting an exception?

I can definitely break the Linq query and use if...else to check this out. But, is there any efficient and nice way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to first do a Linq query that finds all elements that have the name "customers" and then proceed with the second half of your query if you have 1 or more elements to work with:

```
elements = elements.Where(n => n.Name.LocalName.Equals("customers"));
if (elements.Count() > 0)
{
    customer.ID = elements.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "id").FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Someone with more Linq knowledge may have a more elegant solution.

Comment: This will not work. Because, first of all elements.Count() is always >0 because of other sections in XML present. Secondly there can be null returned in second Where() searching for "id" and hence null.FirstOrDefault() will throw the same exception.

Comment: [Where() will not return null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx), only an empty enumerable list at worst, so I suspect you are getting a null pointer exception from somewhere else. Likely FirstOrDefault() is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` will never return `null`. `FirstOfDefault` will, though, and then calling `Value` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

What you should do is take advantage of the [built in explicit conversions from `XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
customer.ID = (string)elements
    .Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "customers")
    .Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "id")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you only need a `string`, the slightly more verbose alternative is to select `Value` and then call `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
customer.ID = elements
    .Where(n => n.Name.LocalName == "customers")
    .Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "id")
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```